# Find an IP change during user's navigation on website

Tags: asp.net, security, ip

What is the best way to find that the user has changed his/her IP address during his navigation?

This is a method for the paying websites in security checks.

Comment: if the user is on a mobile, and their phone switches between wifi and mobile data, their IP address would change, legitimately

Comment: Indeed, there are plenty of reasons a legitimate user's IP address can vary during a session. Please don't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uses a session's to store the current ip address then check it each time. this is a php example but link for asp.net at bottom

```
<?php

// Start the session & set ip after login
session_start();
$_SESSION["thereip"] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>

<?php
// Check ip on each page
session_start();
$currentip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$loggedinip = $_SESSION["thereip"];

if($currentip <> $loggedinip){
  //We Have a problem charle
}
?>
```

Of course this is only a small example and can be done better 
http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp